# How to sum the digits of integers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I'm trying to get a sum of digits list from an integer list.

In:

```
 list=[12,37,44,96]
```

Out:

```
[3,10,8,15]
```

I have tried tons of methods and havent solved yet.

Comment: How do you find he sum of digits of _one_ number?

Comment: ^^If you have a function that'll work on a single number, you can use list comprehension or `map()` to apply to all list numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner should do:

```
result = [sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number)) for number in lst]
```

Basically you have to go from int to strings to get the digits and then back to ints to be able to sum them up.

Note: I renamed your list variable to lst to avoid confusion between variable names and keywords.

Comment: It works, thank you for this useful solution.